# Замена элементов списка Python

Tags: python-3.x

Программно создайте текстовый файл file1.txt, в который запишите следующую строку:
From stephen.marquard@uct.ac.za Sat Jan 5 14:16:28 2018
Используя технологию срезов списков, извлеките из этой строк и выведите на экран отдельно адрес сервера электронной почты, заменив в последней
часть доменного имени za на com, и имя пользователя электронной почты
stephen на jan.

Не могу разобраться ,хэлп.

Comment: В чем разобраться?

Answer (score 1):

```
s = 'From stephen.marquard@uct.ac.za Sat Jan 5 14:16:28 2018'

email = s.split()[1]
print(email)
stephen.marquard@uct.ac.za

repl = [ ['za', 'com'], ['stephen', 'jan'] ]

def replaceiniter(email, s1, s2):
    email = email.replace(s1, s2)
    return email

for s1, s2 in repl:
    email = replaceiniter(email, s1, s2)


print(email)
jan.marquard@uct.ac.com
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def name():
floor = open('file5_4.txt','w')
s = '  From stephen.marquard@uct.ac.za Sat Jan 5 14:16:28 2018'
floor.write(s)
floor.close()
d = s.split()
floor1 = open('file5_44.txt','w')
for i in range (len(d)):
    h = d[i].find('0')
    if h>0:
        q = d[i]
        floor1.write(q[h+1:])
floor1.close()
word=s[h+1:]
word=word.replace('uct.ac.za','com')
print(word)
s = s.replace('stephen','jan')
print(s)
```

name()

Comment: ну вот,кому нужен будет ответ)